# chrome - editable divs - line breaks in the middle of words?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I am using content editable divs and I have overflow set to hidden. In Firefox the div's are correctly displayed and if a word is longer that the div the rest is hidden and no line break occurs. Chrome is inserting line breaks in the middle of words that are longer than the div. Is their a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Chrome has 'word-wrap: break-word' style on by default.

in your div, try resetting worp-wrap back to normal and see if that fixes it:

```
<div style="word-wrap: normal;">..</div>
```